# infinite scroll + masonry overlap

Tags: jquery

I'm testing my theme with the Twitter behavior (load more button), but I have a problem.

If the posts are all squared the posts doesn't overlap when clicking the "Load more" button. But if the posts has automatic heights, the posts overlap.

I already looked for a solution in here, but none worked to me.

If I'm doing something wrong just tell me.

This is my code:

```js
$(function () {
    var $container = $('#posts-container')
    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: '.infinite_scroll',
        nextSelector: '.infinite_scroll a',
        itemSelector: '.posts',
        behavior: 'twitter',
        loading: {
            msgText: "",
            finishedMsg: '',
            img: 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAHAAACH5BAUAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=='
        },
    }, function (newElements) {
        var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $newElems.animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
        });
    });

});

var $container = $('#posts-container');
$container.masonry({
    columnWidth: 1,
    itemSelector: '.posts'
});
```

And my blog: http://paulirea.tumblr.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is happening because there is a static height on `#posts-container` (e.g. `665px`) but when you load more posts, `#posts-container` needs to be taller to accommodate the extra items. A search for "masonry adjust height" returns a few encouraging solutions. Try adding this to your `imagesLoaded` function:

```
$('#posts-container').masonry('reload');
```

Comment: The posts reload but still in the wrong place, look at http://paulirea.tumblr.com/

Comment: That doesn't appear to have fixed it but the original diagnosis is still correct. `#post-container` is still 665px tall and it needs to be resized after the new items are added.

Comment: Your problem is made worse by the fact that `<div class="infinite_scroll">` has `position:absolute`. That element will not flow down the page as `#posts-container` resizes. You may need to recode that so it is `position:relative` or `position:static`

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't work, I've tried with height:auto; on my container but it messes up...

Comment: I'm fairly certain that masonry will automatically assign a height to the container and that height will override the height you set in your CSS file. That is why it is important to have masonry reset the height after the extra elements are added. Perhaps try moving my `reload` call below your `appended` call?

Comment: Anything seems to work, I don't know what's wrong. It's strange that it works when the posts have a fixed height...

Comment: I actually did it, I applied reload  + imagesloaded both to the masonry and infinite scroll, and it worked. Thank you very much for your help, without your help it would have been impossible!!